# Jenkins build is slow in stage and fast in Development

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins configuration is in AWS server.I build a code which is in Bit-bucket using jenkins with publish over SSH plugin. I have two SSH server one is Stage and one is Development. While I build to stage the build process is slow, but when I build to Development means the build process is speed. What is the reason???

Comment: Is the instance type same in stage and dev?

Comment: Yes, both are of same type.